# Help with epsilon and Riemann integral

Tags: riemann-integration

I posted this question yesterday, but it could have been written better and it was a bit "disorderly". So I try to post it again:

Given

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    5       & \quad \text{if } x \text{ <3}\\
    7  & \quad \text{if } x \geq3
  \end{cases}$$
were the partitioning is
$$Pn=[0,3−\frac{1}{n},3+\frac{1}{n},4]$$
where
$$n∈N$$
and
$$I=[0,4]$$
make the graph to f and calculate
$$L(fPn),U(f,Pn)$$Find out if f(x) is integrable or not

WHAT I HAVE DONE:

$$L(f,P_n)=5(3-\frac{1}{n}-0)+5(3+\frac{1}{n}-(3-\frac{1}{n}))+7(4-(3+\frac{1}{n}))=22-\frac{2}{n}$$

$$U(f,P_n)=5(3-\frac{1}{n}-0)+7(3+\frac{1}{n}-(3-\frac{1}{n}))+7(4-(3+\frac{1}{n}))=22+\frac{2}{n}$$

To prove that a function is integrable on [a,b] you use this inequality
$$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon$$

So I get that

$$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)=\frac{4}{n}$$
But I don't know how to continue from here. I have only done tasks where I have been given a partition expressed with epsilon beforehand in the text. But here I get an expression with n. And I don't understand how to prove if this inequality holds or not$$\frac{4}{n}<\epsilon$$

Comment: by the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), for all positive $\epsilon\in\mathbb R$, there exists $n$ such that $\dfrac4n<\epsilon$

Comment: Hmm, I read the link. But I don't understand so much. I do find it hard to read math, so that's probably why. So you mean by that property that the inequality hold for every $$\epsilon>0$$ ?And therefor the the function is integrable on I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose $ n$ such that
$$\frac 4n<\epsilon$$

or equivalently,

$$n>\frac{4}{\epsilon}$$

so, you can take for example

$$n = \lfloor \frac{4}{\epsilon}\rfloor +1$$

for example, if $ \epsilon =10^{-2}$, then $n = 401$.

$f$ is then integrable at $ [0,4]$ since for any given $\epsilon>0$,  there exists a Partition $P_n$ (you gave), with $n = \lfloor \frac{4}{\epsilon}\rfloor +1$, such that

$$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon$$

Comment: Ohh, okay I see. But how does this tell me if the function is integrable or not on $$I=[0,4]$$? And where does the +1 come from in your last expression?

Comment: if you don't add $1$, $n$ might not be greater than $\dfrac4\epsilon$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It could even be smaller.